# Regular Expression:- String can contain any characters but should not be empty

Tags: regex, grails, groovy, regex-negation

My requirement is

> "A string should not be blank or empty"

Eg., A String can contain any number of characters or strings followed by any special characters  but should never be empty  for eg., a string can contain "a,b,c" or "xyz123abc" or "12!@$#%&*()9" or " aa  bb  cc "

So, this is what i tried
 **Regex for blank or  space:-**

```
 ^\s*$ 
^ is the beginning of string anchor
$ is the end of string anchor
\s is the whitespace character class
* is zero-or-more repetition of
```

I'm stuck on how to negate the  regex ^\s*$  so that it accepts any string like "a,b,c" or "xyz" or "12!@$#%&*()9"

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why is this tagged "grails"?  If you're looking for domain class validators you could just use `blank:false`.

Answer (score 3):

No need for a regex. In Groovy you have the [`isAllWhitespace`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#isAllWhitespace%28%29) method:

```
groovy:000> "".allWhitespace       
===> true
groovy:000> "  \t\n ".allWhitespace
===> true
groovy:000> "something".allWhitespace
===> false
```

So asking `!yourString.allWhitespace` should tell you if your string is something else than empty or blank :)

Answer (score 1):

`\S`

`\S` matches any non-white space character

Each character class has it's own anti-class defined, so for `\w` you have `\W` for `\s` you have `\S` for `\d` you have `\D` etc.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Your regex engine may not support `\S`. If this is the case you use `[^ \t\v]` if you support unicode (which you should) there are more space types that you should watch for.

If both your regex engine and you support unicode AND `\S` is not supported by your regex engine then you'll probably want to use (if you care about people entering different unicode space types):

`[^ \r\f\t\v\u0085\u00A0\u1680\u180E\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200A\u200B\u2028\u2029\u202F\u205F\u3000\uFEFF]`

http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode

Comment: Hi omnipotent, \S+ doesnt work for string in my example"" aa bb cc ". It checks for spaces/blanks through out the string. But i'm looking for something like a text field should never be blan but the string inside a text field can contain white spaces like "aa bb cc ". Any suggestions would be of great help

Comment: Are you trying to match the entire string?  Because that regex doesn't try to match the entire string.

Comment: yes, i'm m trying out for something like a text field should never be blank but the string inside a text field can contain white spaces like "aa bb cc ".

Comment: Yes, but if `\S` matches anywhere in the string then it's not blank.  It doesn't need to match the entire string.

Comment: \S fails for "aa bb cc " . if you can please suggest  me the negation of regex ^\s*$ , that would really solve my problem.

Comment: `^\S$` fails for "aa bb cc ", `\S` matches "aa bb cc ".  Because it matches at offset 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, and 7.  It doesn't match the entire string.  Your regex engine may not support `\S`.  If this is the case you use `[^ \t\v]` if you support unicode (which you should) there are more space types that you should watch for.

Answer (score 1):

to me two simple ways to express it are (both no need for anchoring):

```
s.trim() =~ /.+/
```

or

```
s =~ /\S+/
```

the first assumes you know how trim() works, the second assumes the meaning of \S.
Of course

```
!s.allWhitespace
```

is perfect, again if you know it exists

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression will ensure that a string contains at least 1 non-whitespace character.

```
^(?!\s*$).+
```

**Note:** I am not familiar with groovy. But I would imagine there is a native functions (`trim`, `empty`, etc) that test this more naturally than a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

is this in a grails domain class?

if so, [just use the blank constraint](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/blank.html)